# Cant access 'User stories' or features in Azure DevOps Board. (only Epics and issues)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

as a new Azure account holder I have started a new DevOps Board for personal use and to practice Scrum. But when I click on 'Add Work Item'  I am only able to select from Epics, Issues or Tasks. I also want to be able to select user stories and Features.

[image]

Have just tried adding different work items of the types I can acceess to see if this will open up further options but to no avail

Comment: Go to the [Project Settings > Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), and show us what you see.

Comment: heres what i could find

Comment: wont let me paste the screen shot...

Comment: Sounds like you have a basic process template, the different templates define the types of work items that should be available, their names and the hierarchy. You can also edit the process template to add in your own work items

Comment: (edit your question instead of trying to post images into comments, we communicate with you via comments, you respond through edits)

Comment: Yeah i do have a basic! I'll look at how I can change it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default setup if you have used [the `Basic` process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#default-processes)

[image: basic process template]

You can edit the current process template, but you cannot change it. To change the process template you will need to create a new project. If you only need to make minor changes, then you can add the missing work items to your basic template, but there are internal workflows that will not function as you expect, as defined here: [Workflow states, transitions, and reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#workflow-states-transitions-and-reasons)

If you are just starting out in this project, please read through the different process templates and start again with the template that aligns with the development process that you would most like to adopt.